# Swtiching row statement in MySQL returns nothing

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

I am currently writing a MySQL plugin and want to read out of my database every first row where the second row has a special value:

```
private String ip;

public MySqlNPCData(String host, int port){
    this.ip = host + ":" + port;
}

public List<UUID> getUUIDs(){
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT UUID FROM npc_data WHERE IP = ?");
        ps.setString(1, ip);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<UUID> IDs = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!rs.next()) {
            rs.close();
            return null;
        }
        while(rs.next()) {
            IDs.add(UUID.fromString(rs.getString("UUID")));
        }
        for(UUID s : IDs){
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }
        return IDs;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean contains(NPC npc){
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT IP FROM npc_data WHERE UUID = ?;");
        ps.setString(1, npc.UID.toString());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        return rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void save(NPC npc){
    if(!contains(npc)){
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO npc_data (UUID,IP,WORLD,X,Y,Z,YAW,PITCH,SKIN_UUID) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
            ps.setString(1, npc.UID.toString());
            ps.setString(2, ip);
            ps.setString(3, npc.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
            ps.setDouble(4, npc.getLocation().getX());
            ps.setDouble(5, npc.getLocation().getY());
            ps.setDouble(6, npc.getLocation().getZ());
            ps.setFloat(7, npc.getLocation().getYaw());
            ps.setFloat(8, npc.getLocation().getPitch());
            ps.setString(9, npc.uuid);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE npc_data SET IP = ?, WORLD = ?, "
                    + "X = ?, Y = ?, Z = ?, YAW = ?, PITCH = ?, SKIN_UUID = ? WHERE UUID = ?;");
            ps.setString(1, npc.UID.toString());
            ps.setString(2, ip);
            ps.setString(3, npc.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
            ps.setDouble(4, npc.getLocation().getX());
            ps.setDouble(5, npc.getLocation().getY());
            ps.setDouble(6, npc.getLocation().getZ());
            ps.setFloat(7, npc.getLocation().getYaw());
            ps.setFloat(8, npc.getLocation().getPitch());
            ps.setString(9, npc.uuid);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it always returns nothing in the System output, can anybody please help me? Thank you very much

Comment: How do you define "first row"? When you are not selecting multiple rows (e.g. by ID, as in your query), how can there be anything else than a first row? SQL (afaik) does not have some "internal order" that you should rely on, but you should rather tell in your query, which all rows you want to select (e.g. by Condition).

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

When working with JDBC, the container does some work for you, but not a lot. So you have to take this into account.

1) The block:

```
    if(!rs.next()) {
        rs.close();
        return null;
    }
```

is not needed: The `rs.next` returns false if there is no data.

2) The style in which you retrieve connections most likely leads to not closing the connections:

`MySQL.getConnection()` gets you a connection, however it is not closed explicitly. In (for example) Tomcat this most of the time leads to a maximum connection use on MySQL and then an exception in Java because no new connections can be opened. A better style is to open a connection, and close it explicitly, as well as all your other JDBC connected resources:

```
Connection conn=MySQL.getConnection();
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;
try {
  ... All you database actions
} finally {
   try { if(ps!=null) ps.close(); } catch(Exception exp) {}
   try { if(rs!=null) rs.close(); } catch(Exception exp) {}
   try { conn.close(); } catch(Exception exp) {}
}
```

You can of course wrap this close into the MySQL class you are using so you do not have to write this everywhere.

3) This also mean that the code:

```
public boolean contains(NPC npc){
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT IP FROM npc_data WHERE UUID = ?;");
        ps.setString(1, npc.UID.toString());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        return rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

has to be rewritten to no return `rs.next()` but to return an explicit object instead:

```
public boolean contains(NPC npc){
    Connection conn=MySQL.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    boolean retVal=false;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT IP FROM npc_data WHERE UUID = ?"); 
        ps.setString(1, npc.UID.toString());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        retVal=rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         try { if(ps!=null) ps.close(); } catch(Exception exp) {}
         try { if(rs!=null) rs.close(); } catch(Exception exp) {}
         try { conn.close(); } catch(Exception exp) {}
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Watch the removal of the `;` from the `SELECT` statement:
Original code:

```
"SELECT IP FROM npc_data WHERE UUID = ?;"
```

Should be:

```
"SELECT IP FROM npc_data WHERE UUID = ?"
```

The `;` can indicate a multiple statement and can lead to no values returned.

More work needs to be done on your code, but I think you get the idea.